# Соответствие между хеш функциями и хеш алгоритмами в С#

Tags: c#, ооп, .net, хеширование, visual-studio

Есть прога, вычисляющая хэш-код. Тип хэш функции выбирается из списка, а переменная `HashAlgorithm` - alg, присваивается в обработчике кнопки вычислить, в зависимости от выбранного элемента списка, с помощью switch. Хочу создать класс `Algorithm`, в котором будут приватные поля с именем хеш функции и хеш алгоритма (естественно строковое представление названия хэш алгоритма может не совпадать с именем хеш функции, например, `MD160` и `RIPEMD160`), и, в дальнейшем, создавать объект этого класса и работать с ним не используя switch. Но возникает вопрос как организовать соответствие названий хеш функии и хеш алгоритма? Скажите, пожалуйста, какие есть для этого методы, желательно указать конкретные названия? Если в выпадающем списке хранятся названия хеш функций, то необходимо по названия хеш функции вернуть соотв. хеш алгоритм.

Answer (score 2):

```
//делегат хэш-функций
delegate string HashAlgDelegate(string)

//хэш-функции
public string MD160(string str){...}
public string RIPEMD160(string str){...}

//словарь соответсвий названий функций и функций
Dictionary<string,HashAlgDelegate> d = new Dictionary<string,HashAlgDelegate>();

//или просто

Dictionary<string,Func<string,string>> d = new Dictionary<string,Func<string,string>>();

//добавляем соответствия
d.Add("MD160",MD160);
d.Add("RIPEMD160",RIPEMD160);

//или просто:
d.Add("MD160", s => { ... });
d.Add("RIPEMD160", s => { ... });

string SomeString = ...;
string HashString;

//и используем
HashString = d["MD160"](SomeString);
```

примерно так?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял что вы хотите, то почитайте [это](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)).